# How can I target a deeply nested object in google realtime database?

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I want to make a cron job that deletes deeply nested objects in my realtime database that are older than 24 hours.

I have looped through and reached the deeply nested object, but I can't grab/target the value of "addedTime" in the object. How do I grab that value so I can run `.remove` on the parent? So far, it comes back as undefined or it throws an error.

```
  .schedule("every 1 hours")
  .onRun(context => {
    const rootDatabaseRef = admin.database().ref("ghostData/");
    return rootDatabaseRef.ref.once("value").then(function(snapshot) {
      console.log("snap", snapshot.val());
      snapshot.forEach(function(userSnapshot) {
        let buckets = userSnapshot.val().buckets;
        console.log("buckets", buckets);
        buckets.forEach(function(bucket) {
          let currentTimeYesterday = new Date(
            new Date().getTime() - 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
          ).getTime();
          let addedTime = bucket.val().addedTime;
          console.log("curr time", currentTimeYesterday);
          console.log("addedTime", addedTime);
        });
      });
```

Here is the data in my realtime database as well as the logs from the serverless cloud functions:

[image: data structure]
[image: logs1]
[image: logs2]

Comment: It looks like your post is missing a few things.

Comment: Hey Doug, can you elaborate? The first goal is to target "addedTime" which I cannot.

Comment: The links you added don't show up. Note that it is (by far) best to have all information inside the question itself, and not in links to external services.

Comment: Makes sense. I have added everything to the question. Hopefully it provides more information.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having problems with looping, because when you do this "buckets.forEach(function(bucket)" --> bucket in your case is the first element of the list ,
and every element has a nested dictionary , so first you have to iterate the dictionary and for each key in the dictionary , you'll get another dictionary , and you've to grab
only the added-time value.

I know it's difficult to understand but I think it's happening because you're not looping correctly.

Try the code below or something similar.

```
buckets.forEach(function(bucket){
   let currentTimeYesterday = new ......
   bucket.forEach(function(dict){
       Object.keys(dict).forEach(k => {
           console.log(k, ':', dict[k].addedTime);
           let addedTime = dict[k].addedTime;

       });
    ....
   }
  ....
}
```